# How do I remove a Delta Stryke single handle bathroom sink faucet?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I am trying to remove a Delta Stryke Single Handle Bathroom Sink Faucet handle. There is no set screw on this model.  I have spoken to Delta and they have told me that you simply pull up on the handle... that's a no go, it doesn't budge.

What do I do from here?

Comment: How long has it been installed? It's entirely possible that it's just simply stuck. Something like WD40 or PB Blaster sprayed up under the handle might help to break the corrosion/rust/gunk that has likely built up over the years.